# Question regarding pronoun in "Let you and I/me ..."

Tags: grammar, pronouns, writing, relative-pronouns, learning

In my grammar book the answer for the following sentence is 'me'

Let you and ___ try what we can do ( I,me)

Why can't I use "I"? Both subjects seems to be in nominative case.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Let's you and I/me be fair with each other."](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/223895/lets-you-and-i-me-be-fair-with-each-other)

Comment: I don't think they're similar sentences. In this sentence 'let' is used which I think has a different meanings than 'let's'

Comment: Sven Yargs addresses the 'Let us ...' variant before he addresses the ''Let's ...' variant. The analyses are very similar. For the 'Let's' expressions: both expressions are used roughly equally frequently [[Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Let%27s+you+and+I%2CLet%27s+you+and+me&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CLet%20%27s%20you%20and%20I%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CLet%20%27s%20you%20and%20me%3B%2Cc0)], both are non-standard/dialect/colloquial, both are quite rare.

Comment: But in the original example, it's **not** _let us_, or _let's_. It's _let_. So do we assume a typo?

Comment: No it's not a typo. The original sentence is - Let you and ___ try what we can do. (I, me). I'm still confused why the answer of this sentence is 'me' in my book.

Comment: To let is to allow. *Allow me to say*...not allow I or allow you and I.

Comment: The generic advice (remove the *and*) applies here: does “let I try...” sound right to you?

Comment: "Let us try..." (with the pronoun in the object case) would be correct. Likewise "Let you and me try.." (with "me" . in the object case). The thing to note is that, despite what the sentence *means*, *grammatically*, the noun phrase that follows "let" is not a subject.